# How to add a class to empty h1 with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add a class 'hideme' to a empty div.

```
<div id="infocontent" class="grid_15 prefix_1">

     <h1 id="mainhead" class="grid_15 alpha omega" ></h1>
     <div id="infoinner" class="grid_13 prefix_1 suffix_1 alpha omega">


    <FORM ACTION="command.asp" METHOD="get" NAME="artForm">

   ....
   .....
```

I made this but something wrong.

```
$function(){
var contentid = $('#mainhead');
var content = contentid.html();
if (content===''){
    contentid.addClass('hideme');
}
})
```

Update: Sorry it was empty h1.

Comment: What do you expect from invalid HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div>` isn't empty; it contains all subsequent content until the end of `<div id="infocontent">`.

## Close your tags!

*always!*

As other people have mentioned, your code can be simplified by using the [`:empty` selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/):

```
$('#mainhead:empty').addClass('hideme');
```

If the `<div>` is not empty, this selector will not match any elements, and the line will do nothing.

Comment: He said `div` but I think he meant "empty element."

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$function(){
var contentid = $('#mainhead');
var content = contentid.html();
if (contentid.is(':empty')==''){
    contentid.addClass('hideme');
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
if (contentid.is(':empty')) {
  contentid.addClass('hideme');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
   $("div:empty").addClass('hideme');
```